# rmr2 from.dfs results in R session terminated

Tags: r, hadoop

I am new to hadoop and try to get started with. I have "successfully" set up a single node cluster on a server and try to get started using R and the rmr2 package to run MapReduce jobs. But I am not even able to read from the hdfs. When I am executing the following commands from R everything seems to be fine:

```
> Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop")
> Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING="/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.jar")
> 
> library(rmr2)
Loading required package: Rcpp
Loading required package: RJSONIO
Loading required package: bitops
Loading required package: digest
Loading required package: functional
Loading required package: stringr
Loading required package: plyr
Loading required package: reshape2
> rmr.options(backend="hadoop")
NULL
> 
> v <- keyval(1,2)
> to.dfs(v, "/user/dittmanc/test")
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14/01/15 10:26:35 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/01/15 10:26:36 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.deflate]
[1] "/user/dittmanc/test"
```

Checking from the unix terminal if the file exists with the following command:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/dittmanc
```

The file is there!

Now trying to read the file:

> from.dfs("/user/dittmanc/test")
>       DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated. Instead use the hdfs command for it.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14/01/15 10:34:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/01/15 10:34:21 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/01/15 10:34:23 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.deflate]
```

Executing this leads to a R session Error abnormal termination without any further messages. Executing the code with

```
rmr.options(backend="local")
```

and the code works fine. So it seems to be a missconfiguration of hdfs or something like that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: which Hadoop distribution do you use?

Comment: I have downloaded the plain apache version from this url: http://www.trieuvan.com/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.2.0/hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz I forgot to mention that I had installed hadoop on the server previously, so there might be some leftovers interfering. I'll probably make a clean setup of the server and try again.

Comment: It seems like it was an issue with the previous installation. I have reinstalled the server and setup hadoop again and everything works as expected.